# How to download Google Calendars as ICS file with REST API?

Tags: rest, calendar, icalendar

I want to download all calendars as ICS files from Google with using a REST API.

The simplest way is to use the Google Calendar interface. There is a function to simply download all calendars as ICS files in one ZIP file. But this is not what I want.

I realized the OAuth2 login and the Calendar API works well, but I can't find a way to use the ICS file download.

There is one solution - after making the calendar public I can use:

```
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/{calendarId}/public/basic.ics
```

But making the calendar public is no solution for me.

There is a second solution: make a list of private addresses in the code and use them to download. But that is no solution either as the script should get the list of calendars from the API itself. There, I do not find the private address, only the calendar ID.

Has anybody an idea how to solve it?